# Formset Factory Make Fields Required

Tags: django, python-3.x, formset

I am using a `modelformset_factory` in Django to have a user fill out an unknown number of fields.

I have made the fields required but in the HTML rendering Django does not add `required` to the HTML element, looking around online this seems to be a common issue but I have not seen any valid answers that apply for what I want and I feel like this should be simple.

How do I make Django add the required tag to appropriate HTML elements for a Formset?

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Media:
        js = (formset_js_path,)

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseOrderItems
        fields = ['name', 'vendor', 'quantity', 'price', 'description']
        labels = {
            'name': 'Item',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.fields['description'] .widget.attrs['required'] = 'required'
        self.empty_permitted = False

        self.fields['description'] = forms.CharField(
            required=False,
            label='Description',
        )

    def clean(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        # print(cleaned_data)



ItemFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    PurchaseOrderItems,
    form=ItemForm,
    extra=0,
    min_num=1,
    validate_min=True,
    can_delete=True,
)
```

Here is the HTML rendered for the name field, no `required` yet in my model it certainly is, so if this form is submitted I get DB errors because of empty values:

```
<input type="text" name="form-0-name" maxlength="150" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-name">
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.10/#forms):

> Required form fields now have the required HTML attribute. Set the new
>   Form.use_required_attribute attribute to False to disable it. The
>   required attribute isn’t included on forms of formsets because the
>   browser validation may not be correct when adding and deleting
>   formsets.

So if you want to disable, from your view you must submit the form in this way. This will affect all your fields.

```
form = ItemForm(use_required_attribute=False)
```

However, if you only want to affect some you must do the previous step and also in your form add this

```
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'required': ''})
    self.fields['vendor'].widget.attrs.update({'required': ''})
    self.fields['quantity'].widget.attrs.update({'required': ''})
    self.fields['price'].widget.attrs.update({'required': ''})
    self.fields['description'].widget.attrs.update({'required': 'False'})
```

On the other hand I see that you are not using widgets in your form you should also use them to make it work.

```
  widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(),
        'vendor': forms.TextInput(),
        'quantity': forms.TextInput(),
        'price': forms.TextInput(),
        'description': forms.TextInput(),
    }
```

I put all the fields as TextInput, but look for what is indicated according to the type of data here [Field types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types).

Comment: Well, your answer provides doc references stating the question I am asking, so thanks but I think you misunderstood my question so this is unhelpful. I want the required fields to have the required attribute by default. In no way shape or form do I want them disabled as I can't enforce entered data. Formsets, as you posted in the docs I've already read, do not offer this. Outside of a complete front-end solution which I've already implemented, I am trying to find a Django way to do this.

Comment: If you want all your fields to have the required attribute by default, set use_required_attribute to True

Comment: If you do that it does not matter, the formset fields are still rendered without the required attribute regardless of the value of the `use_required_attribute`...as you noted from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the `formfield_callback` argument of the `modelformset_factory`:

```py
from django import forms
from django.db.models import Field
from .models import MyModel

def make_required(f: Field):
    formfield = field.formfield(
        # Optionally override any detail about the formfield
    )
    formfield.widget.attrs['required'] = formfield.required
    return formfield

form_class = forms.modelformset_factory(
    MyModel,
    formfield_callback=lambda field: field.formfield(required=True),
)
```